# Preserve Gradients while tracing PNG

Tags: inkscape, svg, png, corel-draw, image-trace

I'm trying to convert a PNG to SVG by using trace tool. The problem I'm facing is that the resulting image doesn't preserve gradients properly.

Here are two versions of the image that I'm able to produce at my best. One color and the other black-white.

[image: Side-by-side comparision of the image]

Can you show me how can I increase the quality of the generated image such that the gradient is preserved exactly as it is?

EDIT: Original High Quality Image is here - http://lenagold.narod.ru/fon/clipart/l/lev/leon45.png

Answer (score 1):

The Image Trace tool is a good tool to start with, but after that you have to clean up the result. 
To have a nice ribbon, I would select the ribbon segments, go to the Pathfinder palette and click on Unite to have one object, and then fill it with a gradient. There are also gradients in the lion (one for the head and one for the body), you could use that technique too.